# Canvas particles arch

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

It's about Cavas animation.
How do I make my particles are not cubes but circles?
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/NGrdanjski/pen/XKkwAY)

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:#000000;
}
```

JS

```
var cvs = document.createElement('canvas'),
    context = cvs.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(cvs);

var numDots = 300,
    n = numDots,
    currDot,
    maxRad = 900,
    minRad = 100,
    radDiff = maxRad-minRad,
    dots = [],
    PI = Math.PI,
    centerPt = {x:0, y:0};

resizeHandler();
window.onresize = resizeHandler;

while(n--){
  currDot = {};
  currDot.radius = minRad+Math.random()*radDiff;
  currDot.radiusV = 0+Math.random()*200,
  currDot.radiusVS = (0.5-Math.random()*10)*0.00000005,
  currDot.radiusVP = Math.random()*0,
  currDot.ang = (1-Math.random()*2)*PI;
  currDot.speed = (1+Math.random()*0);
  //currDot.speed = 1-Math.round(Math.random())*2;
  //currDot.speed = 1;
  currDot.intensityP = Math.random()*PI;
  currDot.intensityS = Math.random()*0.0005;
  currDot.intensityO = 64+Math.round(Math.random()*64);
  currDot.intensityV = Math.min(Math.random()*255, currDot.intensityO);
  currDot.intensity = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
  currDot.fillColor = "rgb("+currDot.intensity+","+currDot.intensity+","+currDot.intensity+")";
  dots.push(currDot);
}

function drawPoints(){
  n = numDots;
  var _centerPt = centerPt,
      _context = context,
      dX = 0,
      dY = 0;

  _context.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);

  var radDiff;
  //draw dots
  while(n--){
    currDot = dots[n];
    currDot.radiusVP += currDot.radiusVS;
    radDiff = currDot.radius+Math.sin(currDot.radiusVP)*currDot.radiusV;
    dX = _centerPt.x+Math.sin(currDot.ang)*radDiff;
    dY = _centerPt.y+Math.cos(currDot.ang)*radDiff;

    //currDot.ang += currDot.speed;
    currDot.ang += currDot.speed*radDiff/400000;
    currDot.intensityP += currDot.intensityS;
    currDot.intensity = Math.round(currDot.intensityO+Math.sin(currDot.intensityP)*currDot.intensityV);

    //console.log(currDot);
    _context.fillStyle= "rgb("+currDot.intensity+","+currDot.intensity+","+currDot.intensity+")";;
    _context.fillRect(dX, dY, 2, 2);

  } //draw dot
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawPoints);
}

function resizeHandler(){
  var box = cvs.getBoundingClientRect();
  var w = box.width;
  var h = box.height;
  cvs.width = w;
  cvs.height = h;
  centerPt.x = Math.round(w/2);
  centerPt.y = Math.round(h/2);
}

drawPoints();
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Make an animation similar to this
http://cuberto.com/

Comment: Looks like you already have that, you just need to adjust some variables (and specify so in your post please)

Comment: Yes! But I do not know how to tell the particles are circles. Currently are cubes.

Comment: [context.arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) is your friend

Comment: I do not know to apply .arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You're not configuring your colors correctly! When you render circles you set a `fillStyle` and a `strokeStyle`, and since you aren't setting a `strokeStyle`, the circles aren't rendering (see canvas with white background)

After `beginPath()`, before the `.stroke()` command, you need to set the stroke:

```
_context.strokeStyle= "rgb("+currDot.intensity+","+currDot.intensity+","+currDot.intensity+")";
```

---

You're already rendering squares, which means that you have generated a point for each object to occupy. Now pick a radius, probably something small like `1` or `2`, and use `_context.arc` in place of `_context.fillRect`, like so:

```
_context.beginPath(); 
_context.arc(dX, dY, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
_context.stroke();
```

This will make replaces the squares with circles of a radius of `2` (as specified by the 3rd parameter)

Comment: Does not work.
I do not know whether I do something wrong?

exchange
_context.fillRect (dX, dY, 2, 2);

with

_context.beginPath ();
_context.arc (dX, dY, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
_context.stroke ();


But then nothing works. Everything is black ...

Comment: We all forgot to set the `strokeStyle`!

Comment: You do not need the `.fillRect()`, just the `.arc()`. See [my codepen](http://codepen.io/Vulpus/pen/KrQLgy) where I experimented

Comment: One more question. Look this web. http://cuberto.com/ when you set mouse cursor on logo in the centar, the particles begin to leave a trace behind.
How do I do that?

Comment: Their leaving traces behind them, try just not clearing the canvas when you want it to trigger

Comment: Surround the `_context.clearRect` command with an if block which checks your situation. I've modified my pen to toggle traces every 5 seconds. (See [here](http://codepen.io/Vulpus/pen/KrQLgy))

Comment: The last two questions.

How to trigger trace eg if you do hover over an element. eg #trigertrace

And how that whole animation applied to a particular canvas element by ID example I want to show at #spaceanimation?

Comment: `document.getElementById("triggertrace").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){trace=true})` or something similar to trigger trace, and encapsulate the entire code base (except the `cvs` and `context` variables) in a function, rename them, and call the function with them. I'm on mobile now, but I'll update my pen in a moment

Comment: SpeedyNinja i have one more question. Hove i triger this traces on hover over element by ID. For example i have div and his id is logo. Hove i triger trace when i hover over logo div?  
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you want to draw a circle on an HTML5 canvas, this is the code:

```
context.beginPath();    
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

Where:

center(X,Y) is your initial point on the canvas (which from looking at your code will be random)

radius is self-explanatory, you probably want it small for your case

0 is the starting angle for the arch

(2*Math.PI) is the end angle of the arch (in terms of Pi), which will complete a full circle

Hopefully this helped!

Comment: I want to make an animation like this. http://cuberto.com/
But now my particles are cubes.
I want to be circles. I do not know to apply .arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

Comment: Does not work.
I do not know whether I do something wrong?

exchange
_context.fillRect (dX, dY, 2, 2);

with

_context.beginPath ();
_context.arc (dX, dY, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
_context.stroke ();


But then nothing works. Everything is black ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm answering about 15 questions at a time here, I'm bound to mess up eventually

Comment: @SpeedyNinja happens to all of us!